# How to update value of ng-model with the expression in html part

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

Why value of the ng-model is not updated with the expression. Before ng-model is defined value get updated

Value will be updated as soon as phase2 or phase3 changes

```
<input type="text" name="phase1" value="{{phase2 - phase3}}" ></input>
```

Value will not be updated

```
<input type="text" name="phase1" value="{{phase2 - phase3}}" ng-model="phase1"></input>
```

So I think of writing a directive which will evaluate the expression inside the directive and updated the output to model,

Here is html it will look like

```
<input type="text" name="phase1" ng-model="phase1" my-value="{{phase2 - phase3}}" my-model-value></input>
```

Directive:

```
myApp.directive('myModelValue', function(){
return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                model: '=ngModel',
                value: '@myValue'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
                scope.model = scope.value;
            }
        };

});
```

This directive evaluate only at load time, but I want to continuously update/watch as the dependent fields (phase2 & phase3) changes.

I can update value from controller but I want to do it from html. Please help me, it it possible or against the working of angular

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys **I figure out** what I wanted to do. Here is the my final simple but useful directive :)

```
app.directive('myModelValue', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                model: '=ngModel'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
                attr.$observe('myModelValue', function (finalValue) {
                    scope.model = finalValue;
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Usage:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="phase1" my-model-value="{{phase2 - phase3}}"></input>
<input type="text" ng-model="phase1.name" my-model-value="{{valid angular expression}}"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This will watch the  value expression and update the same when value will change

myApp.directive('myModelValue', function(){
return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                model: '=ngModel',
                value: '@myValue'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
                scope.$watch('value',function(newValue){
                      console.log(newValue);
               });
            }
        };
});
here value is a local scope so it will watch the expression
```

Comment: you can simplify your watch expression to one: `$watch('phase2 + phase3', function()...)`

Comment: Oh Sorry I want the expression to be my any custom expression. I don't want to write another directive for every expression. Want to write a generic directive which accepts an expression and evaluate it

Answer (score 0):

In order to continously watch the phase2/3 changes you can make use of $scope.$watch function.

Something like this will work for you:

```
link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
         scope.$watchCollection('[phase1,phase2]', function() {
            //whatever you want to do over here            }
```

and in the scope pass phase1 and phase2 values as well