# Update/Assign ng-model object with expression in AngularJs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. How to `ng-bind` the `totalsum` of value into another `input` in Agularjs , Actually we have a table and we have used filter to get the totalsum value for `Sprice`, then we also got `sprice` totalsum value like `250`, then what we exactly expecting is we need to `bind` this `totalsum` value into another `ng-module` input.... **for example:-** `sprice totalsum` value is `250`, expecting answer of `ng-bind` value is `totalsum value` like `250` ...[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/spnVDJEhqUss1dposy6F?p=preview). we don't know where we have done the mistake so please look into plunker and help us..

- we have a table, in the table we have used filter functionality to get the totalsum value for `sprice`,we got the answer like 250  using of this `<td>{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'sprice'}}</td>`.
- what we expecting we need to `bind` the `sprice` totalsum value to another `ng-module` like `sprice_total` input..expecting answer `250`...
- I have given the plunker as reference [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/spnVDJEhqUss1dposy6F?p=preview) please any one knows the solution help us.

**My controller:-**
  **sprice totalsum filter:-**

```
    .filter('sumOfValue', function () {
return function (data, key) {
    debugger;
    if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key))
        return 0;        
    var sum = 0;

    angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
      if(v.confirm=='cancelled'){
        sum = sum + parseFloat(v[key]);
      }
    });        
    return sum.toFixed(2);
}
```

})

**My Html:-**

```
   <tr ng-repeat="ram in resultValue=(order.orderfood)  | filter: {confirm: '!cancelled'}">

                <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                <td>{{ram.sprice }}</td>


               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>sum</td>

                 <td>{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'sprice'}}</td>

               </tr>
```

I have tried to use the ng-bind to get the value to another input like :-

```
<input type="text" ng-model="sprice_total" ng-bind="sprice_total={{resultValue | sumOfValue:'sprice'}}">
```

- please update the plunker as well to know the solution... thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had created myModelValue directive that will assign your expression to ng-model object

Following is reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818679/how-to-update-value-of-ng-model-with-the-expression-in-html-part)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('myModelValue', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
            attr.$observe('myModelValue', function (finalValue) {
                scope.model = finalValue;
            });
        }
    };
});
app.filter('sumOfValue', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        debugger;
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key))
            return 0;
        var sum = 0;

        angular.forEach(data, function (v, k) {
            if (v.confirm == 'cancelled') {
                sum = sum + parseFloat(v[key]);
            }
        });
        return sum.toFixed(2);
    }
}).controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.order =
  {
      "_id": "5836b64083d9ce0f0078eae8",
      "user": {
          "_id": "579bdf6123f37f0e00a40deb",
          "displayName": "Table 1"
      },
      "__v": 8,
      "total": "1824",
      "ordercar": [],
      "orderfood": [
      {
          "qty": "1",
          "confirm": "placed",
          "sprice": 250,
          "price": 250,
          "customise": "With Onion,Without Onion",
          "name": "Baasha Pizza"
      },
      {
          "qty": "1",
          "confirm": "cancelled",
          "sprice": 250,
          "price": 250,
          "customise": "With Onion,Without Onion",
          "name": "Baasha Pizza"
      }
      ],
      "phone": null,
      "order_source": "",
      "comment": "",
      "payment_mode": "",
      "nop": null,
      "rating": null,
      "bill": false,
      "complete": false,
      "laundry": false,
      "clean": false,
      "roomservice": false,
      "napkin": false,
      "waiter": false,
      "water": false,
      "name": "fgg",
      "created": "2016-11-24T09:43:28.413Z",
      "isCurrentUserOwner": true
  }
});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

body {
    font-size: 14px;
}

table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
table, td, th
{
    border:1px solid black;
}
td{
    padding: 2px;
}
.servicetaxinclusivetrue:before{
  color: green!important;
  content: "\f00c";
}
.servicetaxinclusivefalse:before{
  color: red!important;
  content: "\f00d";
}
.servicetaxexclusivetrue:before{
  color: green!important;
  content: "\f00c";
}
.servicetaxexclusivefalse:before{
  color: red!important;
  content: "\f00d";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>    
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">s.no</th>
                <th rowspan="2"> sprice </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="ram in resultValue=(order.orderfood)  | filter: {confirm: '!cancelled'}">
                <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                <td>{{ram.sprice }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>sum</td>
                <td>{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'sprice'}}</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="text" ng-model="sprice_total" my-model-value="{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'sprice'}}">
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this is what you where expecting

Comment: Hi sir how are you ...!!! thanks  for your valuable answer your really awesome... you are helping to me again and again i never forget you sir...thank you so much....